# using sed, how to change the text on line seven to read seventh?

Tags: linux, sed

using sed, how to change the text on line seven to read seventh?

```
Steve Blenheim:238-923-7366:95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755:11/12/56:20300
Betty Boop:245-836-8357:635 Cutesy Lane, Hollywood, CA 91464:6/23/23:14500
Igor Chevsky:385-375-8395:3567 Populus Place, Caldwell, NJ 23875:6/18/68:23400
Norma Corder:397-857-2735:74 Pine Street, Dearborn, MI 23874:3/28/45:245700
Jennifer Cowan:548-834-2348:583 Laurel Ave., Kingsville, TX 83745:10/1/35:58900
Jon DeLoach:408-253-3122:123 Park St., San Jose, CA 04086:7/25/53:85100
Karen Evich:284-758-2857:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92743:7/25/53:85100
Fred Fardbarkle:674-843-1385:20 Parak Lane, Duluth, MN 23850:4/12/23:780900
Lori Gortz:327-832-5728:3465 Mirlo Street, Peabody, MA 34756:10/2/65:35200
Paco Gutierrez:835-365-1284:454 Easy Street, Decatur, IL 75732:2/28/53:123500
Ephram Hardy:293-259-5395:235 CarltonLane, Joliet, IL 73858:8/12/20:56700
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify line 7, try the following `sed` :

```
sed '7s/.*/seventh/' file.txt
```

Comment: I mean I want to replace line 7 with the word "seventh",  assuming it still works if I change the content of line 7

Comment: @Steve: Try, `sed '7s/.*/seventh/' file.txt`

Comment: See my edited post

Comment: When steve meets Steve =)